# How to rewrite paths for certain file types with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cdn

I move my static files to CDN. There are images, fonts, js, css, and some of them include paths to other files. E.g. file `site.com/fonts/fontname.css` will be at `static.othersite.com/folder/fonts/fontname.css`, and it contain path like `src:url(fontname.eot)`.
How to rewrite all those paths with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|png|svg|css|js|eot|ttf|woff2?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://static.othersite.com/folder%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Keep adding other file extensions to the 2nd `RewriteCond` directive above.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use the rule sting without http starting with // ?

Comment: @DemuriCelidze I've never tried, but I don't think that can be done.